# Only one XSL template out of two that match gets applied, what's wrong?

Tags: xslt

I have an xsl stylesheet that contains the following templates I'm facing the problem with:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<!-- This is the 'parent' matching template that applies two specific templates -->
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'my-element')]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="mode1"/> = <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="mode2"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- This one gets matched and applied from the parent template above -->
<xsl:template match="my-element" mode="mode1">
    ...
</xsl:template>

<!-- And so does this one -->
<xsl:template match="my-element" mode="mode2">
    ...
</xsl:template>

<!-- But then there's also this template that does not get matched -->
<!-- from the parent -->
<xsl:template match="some-element|my-element" mode="mode2">
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

Is it normal that the last template (some-element|my-element) does not match, for example because there is already another one (my-element) that has the same mode (mode2)?

I've tested this with Xalan and Visual Studio 2010 (inside a debugger), they both behave identicaly (i.e. do not consider the very last template as a matching one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever there is more than one matching template, the XSLT processor decides which one template to select for execution, following the rules described in the [W3C XSLT 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#conflict).

**Only one template is chosen and executed**.

One can use **[`<xsl:apply-imports>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#apply-imports)** to invoke an overridden template rule  in an imported stylesheet.

In addition, in XSLT 2.0 it is possible to apply from the chosen template the template that is the "next-best" using the **[`<xsl:next-match>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-next-match)** instruction.

Comment: thanks for the info about <xsl:next-match>, looks like it would nicely address the actual problem that the original author of the stylesheet tried to solve (chaining templates). Unfortunately, the stylesheet is processed by Xalan which supports only XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @user1156361: I am glad that my answer was useful. Would you, please, accept the best answer (by clicking the check-mark next to it)?

Answer (score 0):

Why yes, it's perfectly normal. See [5.5 Conflict Resolution for Template Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict)

Comment: I thought that <apply-templates mode="mode2" _might_ go and apply _all_ matching mode2 templates, which would in such case include both the "my-element" one and the "some-element|my-element" one.

Comment: @user1156361: No, only one template is chosen for execution -- see my answer for details.

Comment: Well, now you know it's not exactly the case.

Comment: @Michael: Right. The whole idea (I'm guessing, it's a legacy stylesheet) was that there is some default processing done by the one of those two mode2 templates, and then some more-specific processing eventually happens in the other template. If that was the case, it obviously never worked.